# Using & inside Less mixins

Tags: css, less, mixins

Here is my mixin code

```
.bleed() {
    &:before, &:after {
        content: " ";
        width: 3%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        .horizontal-gradient(none, #000, rgba(0,0,0,0.0));
        float: left;
    }

    &:after {
        .horizontal-gradient(none, rgba(0,0,0,0.0), #000);
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Here is the code I'm calling it from.

```
.my-class {
   .bleed();
}
```

I'm hoping there is some way to do some thing like .bleed(&); to pass the current selector to the mixin? Right now it is just crashing and not creating the css.

Comment: Doesn't this code compile to `.my-class:before, .my-class:after { ... }`?

Comment: I agree with @cimmanon, the current code already assumes "the current selector" in the mixin because of the `&` appended to the `:before` and `:after`, so what more are you expecting from it?

Comment: It is actually crashing in that no css styles are created by less when I try to use the code above.

Comment: How was anyone supposed to guess that LESS is crashing?  Your code compiles fine using an online compiler:  http://lesstester.com/

Comment: Works fine at [less2css.org](http://less2css.org/) also (assuming one defines the `.horizontal-gradient` mixin).

Comment: I edited the original question to indicate that less is crashing. I will try some of those testers on my whole less file and see if I can figure out whats going on here.

Answer (score 1):

The code does work as is. There was a spelling mistake locally.

Comment: You should probably just delete this whole question.